# How to download files from s3 given the file path using boto3 in python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Pretty basic but I am not able to download files given s3 path.

for eg, I have this `s3://name1/name2/file_name.txt`

```
import boto3
locations = ['s3://name1/name2/file_name.txt']
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'name1'
prefix = 'name2'

for file in locations:
    s3_client.download_file(bucket, 'file_name.txt', 'my_local_folder')
```

I am getting error as `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found`

This file exists as when I download. using aws cli as `s3 path: s3://name1/name2/file_name.txt .`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to have a list of filename paths, then modify your code like shown in the [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html):

```
import os
import boto3
import botocore

files = ['name2/file_name.txt']

bucket = 'name1'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

for file in files:
   try:
       s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(file, os.path.basename(file))
   except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
       if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
           print("The object does not exist.")
       else:
           raise
```

Answer (score 3):

You may need to do this with some type of authentication. There are several methods, but creating a session is simple and fast:

```py
from boto3.session import Session

bucket_name = 'your_bucket_name'
folder_prefix = 'your/path/to/download/files'
credentials = 'credentials.txt'

with open(credentials, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    line = f.readline().strip()
    access_key = line.split(':')[0]
    secret_key = line.split(':')[1]

session = Session(
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key
)

s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

for s3_file in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=folder_prefix):
    file_object = s3_file.key
    file_name = str(file_object.split('/')[-1])
    print('Downloading file {} ...'.format(file_object))
    bucket.download_file(file_object, '/tmp/{}'.format(file_name))
```

In `credentials.txt` file you must add a single line where you concatenate the access key id and the secret, for example:

```sh
~$ cat credentials.txt
AKIAIO5FODNN7EXAMPLE:ABCDEF+c2L7yXeGvUyrPgYsDnWRRC1AYEXAMPLE
```

Don't forget to protect this file well on your host, give read-only permissions for the user who runs this program. I hope it works for you, it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
locations = ['s3://name1/name2/file_name.txt']
for location in locations:
     path_parts = location.replace('s3://', '').split('/')
     bucket = path_parts[0]
     object_key = '/'.join(path_parts[1:])
     local_path = 'my_local_folder/' + os.path.basename(object_key)
     s3_client.download_file(bucket, object_key, local_path)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: usually answers containing only code are considered incopmplete as per the community guideline, try to edit your answer to explain how your code works